# Django - filtering related subset (foreign key) - Error

Tags: django, filter, subset

After inspectdb I have such a model

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    login = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'users'

    def __str__(self) :
        return(self.lastname + ' ' + self.firstname)


class Journal(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column='user_id')
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'journals'
```

In this case I'm trying to get all of the journals that created by specified user after specified date.

```
user = User.objects.get(id=12)
myCount = user.journal_set.filter(created_on>myDay).count()
```

And here I'm receiving next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'created_on' is not defined
```

Can anyone help here: how to count related journals created by specified user in this model?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `myDay` is a python datetime object, you can do:

```
myCount = user.journal_set.filter(created_on__gt=myDay).count()
```

(note the double underscore between the field name and the operator `gt`)

For the various options to filter on fields, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters. If you want journals created on `myDay` included in the count, you would filter with `created_on__gte=myDay` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use ">" to compare dates in Django .filter() function. Please use "__gt=" instead.

So, instead of:

```
myCount = user.journal_set.filter(created_on>myDay).count()
```

try:

```
myCount = user.journal_set.filter(created_on__gt=myDay).count()
```

Related docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#gt